# Resetting Search Widget (SearchView) value

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-widget

I've got 2 activites : the first, `HomepageActiviy`, have a search widget that search data using another activity, `SearchActivity`.

What I want to do is when I go back from `SearchActiviy` to `HomepageActivity`, the search widget go collapsed and with a empty text.

I've tried to do this following thing :

```
public class HomepageActivity extends Activity {
    @TargetApi(11)
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.projectslist, menu);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.homepage_search).getActionView();
            ComponentName component = new ComponentName(this, SearchActivity.class);
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(component));
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
            searchView.setQuery("", false);

        }

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    […]

    @TargetApi(11)
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        launchAsynchronousImageDownload();
    }
}
```

If the widget is well displayed as collapsed, the text in the widget still remember searched text (after I re-open the widget).
How can I reset the text of the widget?

Thanks for any help! ;)

Answer (score 80):

You might also try the following:

```
searchView.setQuery("", false);
searchView.clearFocus();
```

Comment: Ithin there is messing searchView.setIconified(true);

Comment: @TarekEl-Mallah `setIconified` reduces the view to just the icon. It is neither required nor missing when only attempting to clear the query.

Answer (score 47):

**this is the magic**

`searchView.setQuery("", false);` **// clear the text**

`searchView.setIconified(true);` **// close the search editor and make  search icon again**

in the **HomepageActivity** insert the onSaveInstanceState function  after oncreate function

this function will trigger everytime you open a new activity ,
**before opening new activity it will reset the value of Search Widget**

```
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
         searchView.setQuery("", false);
        searchView.setIconified(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me:

First, I declared the menu item variable at the top of the activity:

```
private MenuItem mSearchMenuItem;
```

I defined the variable in OnCreateOptionsMenu():

```
mSearchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
```

I declared invalidateOptionsMenu() in onResume():

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    super.onResume();
}
```

Lastly, I called collapseActionView() on the menu item in onPrepareOptionsMenu().

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    mSearchMenuItem.collapseActionView();

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: It provided the best result in my opinion. Setting the searchView as iconified and clearing its focus would bring the search icon to the left, instead of clearing it completely as if it was never clicked.

Answer (score 4):

```
searchView.setQuery("", false);
searchView.setIconified(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too and it worked if I put it in onPrepareOptionsMenu.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
     SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
     searchView.setQuery("", false);
     // rest of code...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Kotlin

Here's a cleaner solution, it fixes the following:

1. Issue of showing filtered list after screen rotation.
2. Issue of showing filtered list when the user switches to other app and returns back.
3. Issue of search menu shifting to the left when the user returns back.

No need to iconify if you are invalidating, it's done automatically.

---

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    searchView.setQuery("", false)
    (activity as YourActivity).invalidateOptionsMenu()
}
```

Make sure to change `YourActivity` to the Activity name in which you have your Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Just found an ugly way to make it work (read comments to see differences):

```
public class HomepageActivity extends Activity {
    // Declaring SearchView as an instance object
    private SearchView searchView;

    @TargetApi(11)
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.projectslist, menu);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            // Using instance var instead of local var
            searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.homepage_search).getActionView();
            ComponentName component = new ComponentName(this, SearchActivity.class);
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(component));
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
            // Setting query is not anymore required
            //searchView.setQuery("", false);
        }

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    […]

    @TargetApi(11)
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        // Do not need to recreate menu
        /*if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
            invalidateOptionsMenu();*/
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            // Calling twice: first empty text field, second iconify the view
            searchView.setIconified(true);
            searchView.setIconified(true);
        }
        launchAsynchronousImageDownload();
    }
}
```

It's pretty ugly, I think, so if anybody as a better idea, just tell me :)

Comment: hello @kyriog.. 
Though I am answering too late..
But I had the same problem. In onRestart() method I first emptied the text field and then secondly iconify the view. It solves my issue and no need to call setIconified() twice.
`searchView.setQuery("",false);`
`searchView.setIconified(true);`