# show url in searchview android

Tags: android, search, webview, searchview

I want to show the current `URL` of the `WebView` in a `SearchView` menu item.
I know that to get the `URL`, I need to use the `WebView` method `getUrl()`, but I don`t know how to show it after searching the query.

Here my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem =  menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView)searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            String url = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+query;
            PlaceholderFragment.mWebView.loadUrl(url);
            searchView.clearFocus();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Also how do I add the capability to copy and paste this URL?

Comment: can you bit elaborate your requirement ?"but I don`t know,how to show it after searching the query"  you mean after a user search something .you have to display  that url ?

Comment: hide your search view and show textview with url

Comment: @Charuka,sorry for my poor English.
Yes, I mean this "after a user search something .you have to display that url"

Comment: two ways . 1. show it in the search view 2.use another view to display data  .. what do you like ? if u want to set it on the search view ....set the searchView text and you may choose to submit the search that word or not using the boolean parameter ,,searchView.setQuery(searchToken, false);  // true of false to indicate you need to search it or just display

Comment: You can use  `searchView.setQuery(url, false);` in `onQueryTextSubmit` method

Comment: @MayurRaval thanks a lot, it`s work 'searchView.setQuery(url, false);' , but it's show url of my first search . how to change it each time, when i click different urls

Comment: @androiddev 1. you can post your full activity , i can give an answer 2. i can give instructions as a comment what do you prefer ?

Comment: @Charuka, my activity consists about 500 lines of code, so, I think, this is not the best idea:)
I put 'searchView.setQuery(url, false);'  in  onQueryTextSubmit method, it's work only for first seach. When I click on some another site, my url in searchview doesn`t change. I want to change it each time, when click on different links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you use something like that ? You will get user changed url in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method

```
PlaceholderFragment.mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wView, String url)
    {
       searchView.setQuery(url, false);
        wView.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
final SearchView searchView = (SearchView)searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            String url = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+query;
            PlaceholderFragment.mWebView.loadUrl(url);
            searchView.clearFocus();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

If any issue, let me now

**Update**

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

        int id = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
        EditText editText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(id);
}
```

Menu xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/my_search_view"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Search" />
</menu>
```

Now ,you can use that edittext . It is simply hack of searchview ...

Now you can do `selectAll` on click of `searchView`

```
editText.selectAll();
```

Comment: Should I use this method in onQueryTextSubmit() method to load the query, that i`ll put?
I  had also overrided shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wView, String url) method in this activity

Comment: No need You can put outside of that `onQueryTextSubmit()` method, Just added code

Comment: thanks a lot! It`s work perfect . help me please with one more little thing : I want to select all text in searchview by clicking on it ( in edittext i can use allselect() method, and what i can use in searchview?

Comment: I`ve use your code also in onCreateOptionsMenu() after SearchView instance initialization, but it gives me NullPointerException().

Comment: I had nullpointer, because i hadn't set listener for searchview. I add 'searchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View view) { editText.selectAll(); } });' , but nothing happens - I cant select all text (my url) in searchview. P.S: I dont think, that problem was in own layout for searchview (maybe,I am wrong)

Comment: @androiddev, Have you tried to set click listener on `editText`? . If not please do , may be it help

Answer (score 0):

once a user clicks on the `searchView` remove all text in that (if you have) check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24058382/5188159)

start to load the details that user searched in your `webView`

use a listener with your web view and call this every time after you start loading the web view  for a new search

here i am adding all the override methods that you need to know but no need to use them all ..

If you want till the page loads you can display a loading .. look at the comments

```
boolean loadingFinished = true;
boolean redirect = false;

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
            WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        if (!loadingFinished) {
           redirect = true;
        }

        loadingFinished = false;
        webView.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(
            WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        loadingFinished = false;
        //SHOW LOADING IF IT ISNT ALREADY VISIBLE  
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if(!redirect){
           loadingFinished = true;
        }

        if(loadingFinished && !redirect){
            //HIDE LOADING IT HAS FINISHED
        } else{
            redirect = false; 
        }
    }
});
```

Now find the best place you want to display data to the user in that `searchView`  eg : when just page got started loading, when its full loaded

then set it using that `searchView.setQuery(url, false);` inside that selected override method eg: inside `onPageFinished`

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I've used the solution of Mayur Raval